# What does this SMART data say about my Mac HDD?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, hardware-failure, smart

My 2013 MacBook Pro with 500GB HDD was operating extremely slow after having some user login error issues. I backed it up, erased, and reinstalled Mavericks. Now I am getting this SMART data. How serious does this appear to be? Proceed with caution or replace ASAP? I should add it seems to working like new at the moment.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### Proceed with caution or replace ASAP?

**Short Answer:**

Backup this drive and replace **immediately**.

**Long Answer:**

A company called [Backblaze](https://www.backblaze.com/) has collected data on hard drive failures. It has released that data in company blogs, highlighting which manufacturer's drives failed more often than others.

In a [recent blog](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-smart-stats/) it published data indicating exactly which 5 SMART attributes indicate imminent drive failure:

> From experience, we have found the following 5 SMART metrics indicate impending disk drive failure:
>
> - SMART 5 – Reallocated_Sector_Count.
> - SMART 187 – Reported_Uncorrectable_Errors.
> - SMART 188 – Command_Timeout.
> - SMART 197 – Current_Pending_Sector_Count.
> - SMART 198 – Offline_Uncorrectable.
>
> We chose these 5 stats based on our experience and input from others
> in the industry because they are consistent across manufacturers and
> they are good predictors of failure.

The article goes on to suggest:

```
SMART 5: Reallocated_Sector_Count
1-4 keep an eye on it, more than 4 replace

SMART 187: Reported_Uncorrect
1 or more replace

SMART 188: Command_Timeout
1-13 keep an eye on it, more than 13 replace

SMART 197: Current_Pending_Sector_Count
1 or more replace

SMART 198: Offline_Uncorrectable
1 or more replace
```

In your case Smart 5 (raw value 109) is a sign that it should be immediately replaced.

Comment: I should add that it seems to be working perfectly right now. But if the numbers do mean trouble, I'll get on a replacement solution immediately. Thank you!

Comment: @Elliot - It works "perfectly" when it's not reading the bad sectors.

Comment: ok that makes sense. So this means there are 109 bad sectors? What percentage of a 500GB drive is that?

Comment: @Elliot No idea. It depends on the disk geometry. I would back up that disk right away.

Comment: @JakeGould , understand that SMART data from the drive is really only what you see under ‘RAW Value’. everything else you see in the display was added by the developer of the program you’re using to read it. In other words, your disc does not say ‘failing now’, the developer decided to write that there. Only he could tell you what exactly he means with it